# How do I find the sample rate of microphone audio using Skype4Com?

Tags: com, audio, skype

I am using the Skype4Com COM object to intercept audio from the microphone. I know that it is 16 bit mono, but how do I find out what its sample rate is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that there is no facility in Skype4Com to determine the microphone sample rate at the moment. My experiments indicate that it is 16kHz.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's possible to manually set input through a wav-file. The only rate that is allowed, is 16,000 Hz. I think that the rate that is used to transfer, also is 16,000 Hz.